# Using a "domain switcher" to apply Google Analytics tracking ID based on sub domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

I have a site that is deployed to our dev environment. This is then pushed to qa twice a week. The issue is that we need to track hits to both dev, qa and the eventual live site. The code used to track hits is the same that is deployed to the sub-domains and eventually the live site. Ideally, I would like to setup separate profiles to filter hits to each subdomain, but this doesn't seem to work(even using the _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', '.site.com']);

I want to use a Javascript switcher, to check the domain being used to access the site, and apply the tracking ID accordingly. With the following code

```
var trackIDdev = "XX-XXXXXXXX-X"; 
var trackIDqa  = "XX-XXXXXXXX-X";
var trackIDapp = "XX-XXXXXXXX-X"; 

if(document.domain == "dev.sitename.com")       
    trackID = trackIDdev;                       
else(document.domain == "qa.sitename.com")  
    trackID = trackIDqa;            
else(document.domain == "app.sitename.com")     
    trackID = trackIDapp;
```

How can I set the tracking ID into the google analytics from this?

```
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'XX-XXXXXXXX-X']);
```

Comment: Assuming qa is quality assurance, why would you need tracking for the `qa` or `dev` subdomains? Would it not be better just to have the analytics for the live site?

Comment: The powers that be, want to track visits to all subdomains. Otherwise, this would be a simple implementation of GA.